# Select distinct values between two values in different field

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `products` like this:

```
| product_name | start_year | end_year |
|--------------|------------|----------|
| wine         | 2001       | 2012     |
| cheese       | 1999       | 2010     |
| apple        | 2008       | 2015     |
```

What kind of query do I have to run to have all values between `start_year` and  `end_year` where `product = 'apple'`?

This is the desired results:

```
| year |
|------|
| 2008 |
| 2009 |
| 2010 |
| 2011 |
| 2012 |
| 2013 |
| 2014 |
| 2015 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT B.num year FROM
(SELECT start_year,end_year FROM products WHERE product_name='apple') A,
(SELECT tth*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
(SELECT 0 tth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TTHN,
(SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) THN,
(SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) HN,
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TN,
(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) UN) B
WHERE num BETWEEN A.start_year AND A.end_year ORDER BY B.num;
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS EmaOnTheBlock;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE EmaOnTheBlock;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE EmaOnTheBlock
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE products
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> product_name varchar(20),
    -> start_year smallint not null,
    -> end_year smallint not null,
    -> primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO products (product_name,start_year,end_year)
    -> VALUES ('wine',2001,2012),('cheese',1999,2010),('apple',2008,2015);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | product_name | start_year | end_year |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | wine         |       2001 |     2012 |
|  2 | cheese       |       1999 |     2010 |
|  3 | apple        |       2008 |     2015 |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT B.num year FROM
    -> (SELECT start_year,end_year FROM products WHERE product_name='apple') A,
    -> (SELECT tth*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
    -> (SELECT 0 tth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TTHN,
    -> (SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) THN,
    -> (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) HN,
    -> (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TN,
    -> (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) UN) B
    -> WHERE num BETWEEN A.start_year AND A.end_year ORDER BY B.num;
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2008 |
| 2009 |
| 2010 |
| 2011 |
| 2012 |
| 2013 |
| 2014 |
| 2015 |
+------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!